# reader.onloadend is not triggered

Tags: javascript, azure-storage

when i run the below code for multiple files to upload them to Blob storage, the  reader.onloadend is never triggerd. I am following  http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <title>File Uploader</title>
     <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

    var maxBlockSize = 256 * 1024;//Each file will be split in 256 KB.
    var numberOfBlocks = 1;
    var selectedFile = null;
    var currentFilePointer = 0;
    var totalBytesRemaining = 0;
    var blockIds = new Array();
    var blockIdPrefix = "block-";
    var submitUri = null;
    var bytesUploaded = 0;

       $("#output").hide();
       document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        }
         $("#uploadmetadata").click( function(){
                createPackage()
         });
        }); 
        function createPackage(){
        var jsonObject = $("#packagedata").val();   
                $('#success').hide();
                $('#files').hide();                 
                var jqXHR = $.ajax({ 
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "some url here",
                            data: JSON.stringify(jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObject)),
                            async: false,
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function(data) { 
                                $('#success').show();
                                $('#files').show();

                                 return data.id;
                            },
                            error: function (req) {
                            console.log(req);
                            }
                    }); 
                    console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.id);
                    var packagefiles = jqXHR.responseJSON.softwarePackage.softwarePackageFiles;
                                $.each(packagefiles, function (i, ob) {
                                        $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td><span id="fileName"></span></td><td><span id="fileSize"></span> bytes.</td><td><span id="fileType"></span></td><td></td></tr>');
                                });
                    $('#packageId').val(jqXHR.responseJSON.id);
                    return jqXHR.responseJSON.id;

    }

    function getSASUrl(filename) {
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({ 
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "some url here",
                            data: JSON.stringify({"packageId":$('#packageId').val(),"fileName":filename}),
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            crossDomain: true,
                            async: false,
                            success: function(res, status, xhr) { 
                                return res;
                            },
                            error: function (req) {
                            console.log(req);
                            }               
                        }); 
                        console.log(jqXHR);
        return jqXHR;
    }       



    //Read the file and find out how many blocks we would need to split it.
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {

       var f = evt.target.files; 

        for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) { //for multiple files 
            selectedFile = f[i];
            handleFile();
        }
    }

        //Read the file and find out how many blocks we would need to split it.
    function handleFile() {
        maxBlockSize = 256 * 1024;
        currentFilePointer = 0;
        totalBytesRemaining = 0;
        $("#output").show();
        $("#fileName").text(selectedFile.name);
        $("#fileSize").text(selectedFile.size);
        $("#fileType").text(selectedFile.type);
        var fileSize = selectedFile.size;
        if (fileSize < maxBlockSize) {
            maxBlockSize = fileSize;
            console.log("max block size = " + maxBlockSize);
        }
        totalBytesRemaining = fileSize;
        if (fileSize % maxBlockSize == 0) {
            numberOfBlocks = fileSize / maxBlockSize;
        } else {
            numberOfBlocks = parseInt(fileSize / maxBlockSize, 10) + 1;
        }
        console.log("total blocks = " + numberOfBlocks);
       console.log("total blocks = " + numberOfBlocks);
        var xhr = getSASUrl(selectedFile.name); 

        var baseUrl = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Upload-Location");   
        console.log("final SAS" + baseUrl);

        var indexOfQueryStart = baseUrl.indexOf("?");
        console.log(baseUrl.substring(0, indexOfQueryStart));
        console.log(selectedFile.name);
        console.log(baseUrl.substring(indexOfQueryStart));

        submitUri = baseUrl.substring(0, indexOfQueryStart) + baseUrl.substring(indexOfQueryStart);
        console.log("submit" + submitUri);

 }

 var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
            var uri = submitUri + '&comp=block&blockid=' + blockIds[blockIds.length - 1];
            var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                type: "PUT",
                data: requestData,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);
                },
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    bytesUploaded += requestData.length;
                    var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(bytesUploaded) / parseFloat(selectedFile.size)) * 100).toFixed(2);
                    $("#fileUploadProgress").text(percentComplete + " %");
                    uploadFileInBlocks();
                },
                error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                    console.log(desc);
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    };



    function uploadFileInBlocks() {
        if (totalBytesRemaining > 0) {
            console.log("current file pointer = " + currentFilePointer + " bytes read = " + maxBlockSize);
            var fileContent = selectedFile.slice(currentFilePointer, currentFilePointer + maxBlockSize);
            var blockId = blockIdPrefix + pad(blockIds.length, 6);
            console.log("block id = " + blockId);
            blockIds.push(btoa(blockId));
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);
            currentFilePointer += maxBlockSize;
            totalBytesRemaining -= maxBlockSize;
            if (totalBytesRemaining < maxBlockSize) {
                maxBlockSize = totalBytesRemaining;
            }
        } else {
            commitBlockList();
        }
    }

    function commitBlockList() {
        var uri = submitUri + '&comp=blocklist';
        console.log(uri);
        var requestBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>';
        for (var i = 0; i < blockIds.length; i++) {
            requestBody += '<Latest>' + blockIds[i] + '</Latest>';
        }
        requestBody += '</BlockList>';
        console.log(requestBody);
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            type: "PUT",
            data: requestBody,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', selectedFile.type);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestBody.length);
            },
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(desc);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

    }
    function pad(number, length) {
        var str = '' + number;
        while (str.length < length) {
            str = '0' + str;
        }
        return str;
    }


            </script>
         </head>
         <body>
              <form>
              <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
                  <h1>File Uploader</h1>
                    <input id="packageId" type="hidden"/>
                        <input id="txtSAS" type="hidden"/>
                    <p>
                       <strong>Browse Package</strong>: 
            <br/>
            <span class="input-control text">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="packagedata"></textarea><br>
                <button type="button" id="uploadmetadata" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button">Create Package Metadata</button>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>SAS URI</strong>: 
            <br/>
            <span class="input-control text">
                <input type="text" id="sasUrl" style="width: 50%"
                       value=""/>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>File To Upload</strong>: 
            <br/>
            <span class="input-control text">
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" style="width: 50%" multiple />

            </span>
        </p>

            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        File Size
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        File Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                         <strong>Progress</strong>: <span id="fileUploadProgress">0.00 %</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the file is read in `uploadFileInBlocks()` function which you're not calling. To initiate the upload you have to call this method somehow. If you look at the code in the blog post, this method is called on the click on `Upload File` button (from the blog post):

```
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFileInBlocks()"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav... You've nailed it.